# Cannot find a good intermediate real analysis textbook with enough examples/solutions - Any suggestion?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

I am currently taking an intermediate real analysis course, one that is between an undergraduate real analysis course and a graduate real analysis course in terms of difficulty. However, I have not been able to find a book that provides a good number of examples that are clear and concise or that provide some sort of solutions. While I do appreciate books that don't have solutions (as it forces you to work them out yourself), I do like it when I can know if my answer is correct.

To summarize, I guess I'd be looking for the following:

1) Clear examples or solutions (hopefully in detail, lots of textbooks seem to take a lot of things trivially in the interest of space).

2) Pictures or graphs would be nice

3) Covers material like metric spaces (compact, connected, relative), $l^1$ spaces, and normed vector spaces.

Has anyone come across such a book? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where do you belong to? Different countries has different local authors.

Comment: I am currently in the United States, thank you!